# How to add a summed field for each elements in array using aggregate in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I've got documents like this:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId('...')
    statistics: [
        {
            empty: {count: 0}
            correct: {count: 1}
            incorrect: {count: 0}
        },
        {
            empty: {count: 2}
            correct: {count: 3}
            incorrect: {count: 0}
        }
        ...
    ]
}
```

What I want to do is to add a new field called `sum` to each array elements which adds the values inside `statistics` elements. final document should look like this:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId('...')
    statistics: [
        {
            empty: {count: 0},
            correct: {count: 1},
            incorrect: {count: 0},
            sum: 1
        },
        {
            empty: {count: 1},
            correct: {count: 3},
            incorrect: {count: 1},
            sum: 5
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to do so using `aggregation` framework of mongoDB since there are multiple stages before this and want to attach this final stage to that.

Thanks

Comment: Use a `$addFields` stage with `$map` array operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out, `$addFields` and `$map`. And `$mergeObjects`. I just took the chance to practice.

If one of the arguments (`count`s) is missed or not a number, it will return `null`.

```
db.collection.aggregate({
  $addFields: {
    statistics: {
      $map: {
        input: "$statistics",
        as: "d",
        in: {
          "$mergeObjects": [
            "$$d",
            {
              sum: {
                $add: [
                  "$$d.empty.count",
                  "$$d.correct.count",
                  "$$d.incorrect.count"
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

#### [Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/FQ-NFQJNAIa)